# How to do Planar mapping of a texture

Tags: opengl, glsl

When drawing objects we specify texture coordinates in the data of the object itself

```
float vertices[] = {
        // positions          // colors           // texture coords
         0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 1.0f, // top right
         0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 0.0f, // bottom right
        -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,   0.0f, 0.0f, // bottom left
        -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 1.0f  // top left 
    };
```

these texture coordinates give us vertex or edge to edge mapping.

If i want to do planar mapping than i specify the texture coordinates in fragment shader.

```
 texture( material.texture1 , vec2( (gl_FragCoord.x * 0.005)  , gl_FragCoord.y * 0.005 ))
```

Instead of doing this in the fragment shader , is it possible to do this in the code itself.

Comment: Fragment shaders *are* code; they are "the code itself". So what exactly do you mean by this? From where are you trying to set the texture coordinates, and why can't it be in the FS (where the texturing is being done)?

Comment: @Nicol Bolas i mean can i calculate the texture coordinates and than pass them to the shader.

Comment: And who is "i" in this scenario? The Vertex shader? The code writing the data for the vertex buffer which will be used to render the object? And equally importantly... why do you think that will be better than letting the fragment shader do its job?

Comment: @Nicol Bolas the difference is that first code i am sending the texture coordinates , in the the second code i am simple using the fragCoord postion in the screen space for the texture coordinate.

Comment: Yes, I can see that. What I don't understand is what is the problem with this state of affairs.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas i would need to specify in the fragment shader when to use the coordinates passed from code writing the data for the vertex buffer and when to use FragCoord postion.

Comment: @Summit Why do you not specify a texture coordinate attribute always?

Comment: @Rabbid76 i do it in the first case , in the second case how can i know what value to set in the attrib ?

Comment: @Summit The texture coordinates are in rang [0, 1]. `gl_FragCoord.xy` is in the range of the width and height of the viewport. So how do you know to use `(gl_FragCoord.x * 0.005)  , gl_FragCoord.y * 0.005 )`? If you want to wrap a texture on a quad, then the texture coordinates are (0, 0) -> (1,1)